# Join tables with same columns

Tags: python, mysql, sql, join

I load data on daily basis from python into a mysql database and a table "temp_table". I want to join this into the "total_table" so that new values get added to the "total_table"

```
+-----Temp-table-------+
+----------------------+
| id | Price    | Name |
+----+----------+------+
| 3  | 1.000    | C    |
| 4  | 1.500    | D    |
| 5  | 1.200    | E    |
| 6  | 2.000    | F    |


+-----Total-table------+
+----------------------+
| id | Price    | Name |
+----+----------+------+
| 1  | 1.100    | A    |
| 2  | 1.600    | B    |
| 3  | 1.000    | C    |
| 4  | 1.500    | D    |
```

result after joining

```
+-----Total-table------+
+----------------------+
| id | Price    | Name |
+----+----------+------+
| 1  | 1.100    | A    |
| 2  | 1.600    | B    |
| 3  | 1.000    | C    |
| 4  | 1.500    | D    |
| 5  | 1.200    | E    |
| 6  | 2.000    | F    |
```

I have tried LEFT JOIN. Don't get any errors in python but my total-table is not updated

```
 SELECT * FROM total_table
            LEFT JOIN
            temp_table
            ON total_table.id = temp_table.id
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempts? A [mcve] with code will help us to better help you

Comment: This looks more like a `UNION` than `jOIN`. What are the related columns in the two tables?

Comment: If you want to add rows to a table, you have to use `INSERT INTO`. If you want to replace rows, use `UPDATE`. `SELECT` returns a new result, it doesn't modify existing tables.

Comment: All columns/column-names are equal in both tables. I would like to join on ID since the other columns doesn't have unique data. Ok, so I cant use select if I i want the end result to be in the total-table? Then I should use "Update?

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not  comments. PS How is reading an introduction or manual or googling re updating or changing a base table in MySQL not answering your question? Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think you are looking for the UNION operator:

```
SELECT * FROM total_table
UNION
SELECT * FROM temp_table
```

Comment: thanks, will try it

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO total_table
SELECT *
FROM temp_table
```

The `IGNORE` option will make it skip the rows in `temp_table` that duplicate the unique key in `total_table`.

Comment: thanks, will try it

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an `UPSERT` of the temp data.
Via an `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement.

Note that the target table does require a primary key or unique index for this.

> ```
> INSERT INTO total_table
> (id, Price, Name)
> SELECT 
>  id, Price, Name 
> FROM temp_table tmp
> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
>   Price = tmp.Price
> , Name = tmp.Name;
> ```

> ```
> select * 
> from total_table
> order by id;
> ```

| id | Price | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.100 | A |
| 2 | 1.600 | B |
| 3 | 1.000 | C |
| 4 | 1.500 | D |
| 5 | 1.200 | E |
| 6 | 2.000 | F |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4ed5068d9a549b7c9f9346dd5b421ab2)*